# Calculate Date Difference using Partition By and Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to calculate the Date difference between the First Order created and with followup order created. Using the Date diff followed by Partition By and Order by. But it is throwing an Error "The function `DATEDIFF` is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause"

I have tried using Sum, Count and Average - but those will not give the right numbers as these are adding the numbers or averaging it.

```
Select DATEDIFF(day,a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT],b.[DSPCH_CRT_DT]) over (Partition by a.[ASST_ID] Order by b.[SVC_DSPCH_ID]) as 'Duration'
```

I expect this to show the difference between the two order dates

```
FISCAL_YEAR | FISCAL_Quarter | FISCAL_Month | FISCAL_Week | DSPCH_CRT_DT   | Duration
2019          2019Q01          2019M01        201902        2/14/2018 0:00   5
2019          2019Q01          2019M02        201906        3/13/2018 0:00   37
2019          2019Q01          2019M03        201910        4/11/2018 0:00   98
2019          2019Q01          2019M03        201913        5/3/2018  0:00   181
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can DATEDIFF the result of a LEAD or LAG window function to the same result.

Comment: FISCAL_YEAR FISCAL_Quarter FISCAL_Month FISCAL_Week DSPCH_CRT_DT Duration
2019 2019Q01 2019M01 201902 2/14/2018 0:00 5
2019 2019Q01 2019M02 201906 3/13/2018 0:00 37
2019 2019Q01 2019M03 201910 4/11/2018 0:00 98
2019 2019Q01 2019M03 201913 5/3/2018 0:00 181

Comment: Can you give an example pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 
    DATEDIFF(day,a.DSPCH_CRT_DT,LAG(a.DSPCH_CRT_DT) OVER (Partition by a.[ASST_ID] Order by a.[SVC_DSPCH_ID]))
FROM
    Table a
```

Comment: ,DATEDIFF(day,a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT],lag(b.[DSPCH_CRT_DT]) over (Partition by a.[ASST_ID] Order by b.[SVC_DSPCH_ID])) as 'Duration' I used the code now

Comment: But the First order is showing Null - I want that also to be calculated. I tried both Lead and Lag

Comment: If you say so, you did not post you query so I can only guess at what b pointed to. Did it work?

Comment: You could also set up a CTE to fetch your b data and virtualize a MIN(x) or MAX(x) for the first record.

Comment: Thanks Ross it fixed the issue. I am still grappling with some other issue.